# Why is $2^x>2x$ when $x>2$?

Tags: inequality

I came across this inequality while trying to prove that a function was increasing for $x>2$. I checked it graphically and it's true but I don't have a particularly good proof of it.

So, can you tell me why $2^x>2x$ when $x>2$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just take the derivative:  $\frac d{dx}(2^x-2x)=2^x \log 2 -2$.  For $x \gt 2$ we have $2^x \log 2 -2\gt 4 \log 2 -2 \gt 0.772$

Answer (score 2):

You could use proof by induction if x is an integer.

Base Cases: $2^3=8>6=2(3)$

Inductive Step: Assume that $2^{n-1}>2(n-1)$ where $n-1\ge{3}$. Then, $2^{n-1}+2^{n-1}>2(n-1)+2^{n-1}>2(n-1)+2=2n$. Note that $2^{n-1}+2^{n-1}=2(2^{n-1})=2^n$. Thus, $2^n>2n$.

Comment: This is fine if we were just checking for integral $x$.

Comment: Answer was edited to reflect that it is valid if x is an integer.